# java смена значка у ярлыка

Tags: java, swing

Необходимо сменить значок у ярлыка на рабочем столе
p.s.знаю только часть директории основного файла(\soft\dist)

Пробежался по рабочему столу и получил список файлов с .lnk расширением, как получить путь (Рабочая папка) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
File[] files = javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory().listFiles();
    if (files != null) {
        IntStream.range(0, files.length).mapToObj(e -> files[e]).filter(e -> e.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".lnk")).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Для дальнейшего условия на сравнения директори (\soft\dist)

И если условия вернет тру, как этому ярлыку сказать: смени мне значок на (C:\8735235\nameicon.ico)